# Weird transparency bug that happens with fullscreen or maximized applications

Tags: windows, video, graphics-card, gpu, transparency

CPU: i9-10980HK
GPU 0 (Integrated): Intel UHD Graphics
GPU 1 (Discrete): RTX 3070 Laptop

I have no clue what I'm looking at. I had updated Chrome, Zoom, Nvidia Drivers and I tried restoring all of those but to no avail. When I click a screenshot, it shows up fine, but on the actual screen it's very bright and transparent.
Another thing that is kind of weird and I wouldn't expect, is that task manager is using the integrated GPU instead of the discrete GPU for dwm (window manager).
I ran DISM to check the health and everything, but nothing was corrupted.

Note: Youtube was doing some weird stuff like this, I fixed it by changing the ANGLE backend in chrome to OpenGL. No clue, but that seemed to fix it.

Edit: Forgot to mention, I disabled the Intel UHD graphics driver and it worked fine after that, but the machine was super laggy and slow.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR3HY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

For those who want to know how I instantly fixed this, (TL;DR) I reinstalled the Intel iGPU drivers, which you can find [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/126789/Intel-UHD-Graphics-620).

Long story here: So I kept reinstalling NVIDIA drivers thinking that it's my discrete GPU at fault, but to a slight surprise, it's actually not, and it's instead of my iGPU. Turns out the drivers were actually kinda old, and I hadn't updated them since I got this laptop. I think I updated drivers that were 2.5 years old, so no wonder.

Anyways, the moral of the story, keep your drivers updated. **All of them because Windows is bad**.